# Multiple hidden imports error Pyinstaller

Tags: python, import, pyinstaller, importerror

I have a script which is importing the modules tkinter, pyautogui and pyAesCrypt. (And some others, but those three can not be imported)

If I start my exported application it terminates with an import error. It could not import tkinter. (tkinter is the first module which is imported in the script)

So I know that I have to use *--hidden-import* for the pyinstaller. I edited the hidden-imports in the spec file to

```
hiddenimports=['tkinter','pyautogui','pyAesCrypt'],
```

I retried the installation with pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller Sub.py --specpath=test
```

*Sub.py* is the name of the script.
*test* is the directory, where the spec file is located.

But this did not change anything. Only the hidden-import line in the spec file was empty after the installation.
Have I done something wrong?

Comment: try pyinstaller Sub.spec ?

Comment: @JerryHu Yes. It worked! Thanks.